# Streaming Audio on my website

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio-streaming

I am interested in streaming audio on my website, but I have no clue where to begin. There are two types of streaming I hope to achieve. The first would be streaming a playlist of songs stored on the server and the second would be live audio streaming. Can anybody recomend any good sites or plugins to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) could cover the client side stuff (cross-platform, uses flash) and any web server can be used to serve audio files that could be used in a playlist. Live streaming is a bit more complicated but could be accomplished using [IceCast](http://www.icecast.org/) or [mpd](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki).

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is a streaming audio server.

A Google search should help you locate a server or software that best fits your needs.

Comment: So there isnt a software solution on it's own?