# Streaming chunks of audio (mp3) using Java&JSP for real-time playback through servletOutputStream

Tags: java, jsp, audio-streaming, outputstream, buffering

I am trying to playback audio and keep it continuous and free from skips or blank spots. I have to first receive as bytes in chunks and convert this to mp3 to be streamed by the servletOutputStream. I only start playing once enough bytes have been collected by the consumer in an attempt to maintain a constant flow of audio. As you can see I have hard coded this buffer but would like it to work for any size of audio bytes. I was wondering if anyone had come across a similar problem and had any advice?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {

    private MonitorClass consBuf;
    private InputStream mp3InputStream = null;
    private OutputStream OutputStream = null;

    public Consumer (MonitorClass buf, OutputStream servlet) 
        {
        consBuf = buf;
        OutputStream = servlet;
        }

    public void run() 
    {
        byte[] data;
        byte[] tempbuf;
        int byteSize = 60720; //This should be dynamic
        int byteIncrement = byteSize;
        int dataPlayed = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int buffer = 0;
        boolean delay = true;

        AudioFormat generatedTTSAudioFormat = getGeneratedAudioFormat();

        try
        {       
            while(true) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    data = consBuf.get(); //gets data from producer using a shared monitor class

                    if(data.length >= byteSize) //Buffer size hit, start playing
                    {
                        if(delay) //help with buffering
                        {
                            System.out.println("Pre-delay...");
                            consBuf.preDelay();
                            delay = false;
                        }

                        tempbuf = new byte[byteIncrement];

                        arraySwap(data, tempbuf, start, byteSize);

                        System.out.println("Section to play: " + start + ", " + byteSize);

                        mp3InputStream = FishUtils.convertToMP3( new ByteArrayInputStream(tempbuf), generatedTTSAudioFormat);

                        copyStream(mp3InputStream, OutputStream);

                        System.out.println("Data played: " + byteSize);
                        System.out.println("Data collected: " + consBuf.getDownloadedBytes() );
                        dataPlayed = byteSize;
                        start = byteSize;
                        byteSize += byteIncrement;
                    }

                    if( consBuf.getIsComplete() )
                    {
                        if (consBuf.checkAllPlayed(dataPlayed) > 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Producer finished, play remaining section...");

                            //mp3InputStream = convertToMP3(new ByteArrayInputStream(tempbuf), generatedTTSAudioFormat);

                            //copyStream(mp3InputStream, OutputStream);
                        }

                        System.out.println("Complete!");
                        break;  

                    }

                }  
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != mp3InputStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    mp3InputStream.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {}
            }

            closeStream(mp3InputStream);
            closeStream(OutputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beg your pardon, but I don't see what your question has to do with JSPs. Do you want to embed audio playing in a web page?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I haven't included all the code. This is from a jsp file. Yes, the audio is played through a web page. The servlet outputstream is passed to the consumer. My problem is how to stream it without skips and jumps.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the JSP. Did you check [Streaming Audio on my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045273)?

Comment: The JSP just sets up the servletOutputStream. The jsp is then called from my web page as a webservice. The code I have currently works and streams my live audio bytes back from the server. My issue is creating some sort of buffer that will allow me to play this without skips smoothly while the producer on the server side is writing the bytes to a mutual byte array.